# SQLite3: Selecting N Minimum Values for all IDs

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

Say I have a table `my_table` that has a column `ID` and has another column `Date` and all these records are unique.

I would like to select for all IDs, the records with the lowest N Dates. If I want to do this for N = 1, I have the following below

```
SELECT
    *
FROM my_table r
WHERE
    r.Date = (SELECT Min(Date) FROM my_table WHERE ID = r.ID)
```

How do I generalise this for higher N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite allows the following syntax:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM my_table r
WHERE r.Date IN (SELECT Date FROM my_table WHERE ID = r.ID ORDER BY Date LIMIT 5);
```

Comment: Worked a charm, thanks. Was 5 times quicker than my initial method for N = 1 as well.

Comment: Out of interest, is there an easy way of specifying that there must be >= N records for a certain ID in order for the first N to be selected?

Comment: @rwolst . . . you would have to do this with an additional comparison on the aggregated values.